# ListCollectionView Grouping Multipletimes

Tags: wpf, user-controls, tabs, listcollectionview

I have an usercontrol which Implements **ListCollectionView** when i run this seperately its workin fine, but when i put this in another userControl which is **Dynamic tabControl** which creates **tab** dynamically, the real problem comes when i **create 2nd tab** the **grouping happens 2 times** , if i **create 3rd tab** then **grouping happens 3times**,like so on. i have referneced the link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/493538/Add-Remove-Tabs-Dynamically-in-WPF
for creating dynamic tab, then

```
Public obj As ThumbnailImages

    Private Function AddTabItem() As TabItem
        Dim count As Integer = _tabItems.Count

        ' create new tab item
        Dim tab As New TabItem()

        tab.Header = String.Format("tab{0}", count)
        tab.Name = String.Format("tab{0}", count)
        tab.HeaderTemplate = TryCast(tabDynamic.FindResource("TabHeader"), DataTemplate)


        obj = New ThumbnailImages

        ' add controls to tab item, 
        tab.Content = obj
        obj.SetDataContext(ImageCollection)

        _tabItems.Insert(count - 1, tab)

        Return tab
    End Function
```

**Below code is in my Thumbnail Usercontrol**

```
 Public Sub GroupAndSortImages()

        myCollectionView = Nothing

        myCollectionView = CType(CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Me.DataContext), ListCollectionView)

        myCollectionView.GroupDescriptions.Add(New PropertyGroupDescription("Name"))

        myCollectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(New SortDescription("Name[0]", ListSortDirection.Ascending))

        MyList.ItemsSource = myCollectionView
    End Sub

    Public Sub SetDataContext(ByVal datacontext As Object)
        Me.DataContext = datacontext
        GroupAndSortImages()
    End Sub
```

In the above code i'll create the **new object for my thumbnail usercoontrol when new tab is clicked** when it is first time its working fine as shown below

[image: First time ,first tab loading my thumbnail usercontrol]
when i click for second tab,its grouping two time as shown below andalso in addtion to that this **second grouping also happened in first tab,even though i have used**

```
obj = New ThumbnailImages
```

in **AddtabItem** method

[image: Grouping two times]
[image: Grouping three times]

i'm debugging for long but unable to find out the cause. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Either it can be achieved as said by *Anand* answered above, or it can be done simply by

clearing the **GroupDexcription** before assgning

```
Dim myCollectionView As ListCollectionView

 myCollectionView = CType(CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Me.DataContext), ListCollectionView)

            myCollectionView.GroupDescriptions.Clear()

            myCollectionView.GroupDescriptions.Add(New PropertyGroupDescription("Name"))

            myCollectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(New SortDescription("Name[0]", ListSortDirection.Ascending))
```

Answer (score 0):

Its being grouped twice/more because you have added the same `PropertyGroupDescription` twice/more times.

Define a class level variable to hold the `PropertyGroupDescription` like below

```
private PropertyGroupDescription _NamePropertyGroupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("Name");
```

And then, before adding the `PropertyGroupDescription` just check if it is already added

```
if (myCollectionView.GroupDescriptions.Contains(_NamePropertyGroupDescription) == false)
{
    myCollectionView.GroupDescriptions.Add(_NamePropertyGroupDescription);
}
```

Sorry, the code is in C# but I'm sure you will get the idea behind it.

Comment: ,Thanks for youe reply, by the way i have achieved by clearing the **GroupDescription** before assigning `myCollectionView.GroupDescriptions.Clear()`